# iAd Interstitial ads wont show up

Tags: ios, iad, ads, interstitial

my app Dotcha! is now on the app store and I am trying to make an update in xcode. In my update I fix some minor things and a few major things. My problem is that I screwed around with the Interstitial ads that I had working and now they don't seem to work anymore. Here is my code.

```
func Close(sender:UIButton){

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    InterAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}

func loadAd() {

    println("load ad")
    InterAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    InterAd.delegate = self
}

func interstitiallAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("ad did load")

    InterAdView = UIView()
    InterAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.addSubview(InterAdView)

    InterAd.presentInView(InterAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

    InterAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("Ad Unloaded")
    InterAdView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()

}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("failed to receive")
    println(error.localizedDescription)

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    InterAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}


func RandomInterstitialAd(){

    var RandomAd = arc4random() % 6


    switch(RandomAd){

    case 0:
        break
    case 1:
        loadAd()
        break
    case 2:
        break
    case 3:
        loadAd()
        break
    case 4:
        break
    case 5:
        break
    default:
        break

    }
```

Close button code in viewDidLoad:

```
 closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 30, 30)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "Close:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)


}

var InterAd = ADInterstitialAd()
var InterAdView: UIView = UIView()

var closeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
```

I call the RandomInterstitialAd() function when the a button is pressed. The console prints in load Ad, but the ad never loads. Please help.